# Debugging Python (Jython) code in Anypoint Studio (formerly called Mule Studio)

Tags: python, mule, jython, mule-studio

I'm using Anypoint Studio for developing Mule ESB applications. 
Debugging Java code linked with Mule Java component is working fine in Anypoint.
But I can't figure out how to debug Python (Jython) code from a Mule Python component when debugging a Mule flow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can debug the Python/Jython code with the [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) module, just like normal.

`import pdb`

`...`

`pdb.set_trace()`

`...`

If you run your Mulesoft project in debug mode, you can step through the pdb debugger in your console window (`h` for help). However, note that you will not see any output from each line in your script like you would normally; just a line number tracing the execution. You can still call variables that have been set though. Good luck!